# Need: Replace text with image on Google App Script (Slides)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Trying to write a script that will replace a piece of text on Google slides by an image sourced from a URL in a google sheets list. My script works but only for 1 text. How do I replace multiple texts on the slide ? Not just one. The error message I'm getting is : Page element is not of type shape.

Here is my script

```
function myFunction()  {     
var brandlogosheet = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTEoHil6FFLh2ydXaJ9RlU2n5uv9KPjrAhbQY_8hZXE/edit#gid=1309887859"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(brandlogosheet);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('brandlogoscript');
var values = sheet.getRange('A2:DY3').getValues();
var slides =  SlidesApp.openById("1pFq0ogk1g1_rXxkahOuvAnksysWShozOet6CzF4BcIk"); // SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();

values.forEach(function (page) {
  if (page[0]) {
    var a = page[0];
    var b = page[1];
    var c = page[2];
    var d = page[3];
    var e = page[4];
    var f = page[5];
    var g = page[6];
    var h = page[7];
    var i = page[8];
    var j = page[9];
    var k = page[10];
    var l = page[11];
    var newSlide = defaultSlides[8];
   
    newSlide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque1}}") s.replaceWithImage(a);
      //if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque2}}") s.replaceWithImage(b); // here is where it doesn't work
    });
  }
});
}
```

I GET THE ERROR : Page element is not of type shape.

I would appreciate some help. I feel like I'm missing something. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following script,

```
newSlide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
  if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque1}}") s.replaceWithImage(a);
  //if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque2}}") s.replaceWithImage(b); // here is where it doesn't work
});
```

I guessed that in your Google Slide, the shapes including the texts of `{{T1_Marque1}}` and `{{T1_Marque2}}` are replaced with the image. In this case, the following flow is run in the above script.

1. `if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque1}}") s.replaceWithImage(a);` converts a shape includeing the text of `{{T1_Marque1}}` to an image.
2. The same shape is trying to use as the shape with `if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque2}}") s.replaceWithImage(b);`. In this case, the shape has already been converted to an image. By this, an error like `Page element is not of type shape.` occurs.

I guessed that the reason for your current issue is this.

In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
newSlide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
  if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque1}}") s.replaceWithImage(a);
  //if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{T1_Marque2}}") s.replaceWithImage(b); // here is where it doesn't work
});
```

#### To:

```
newSlide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
  var obj = { "{{T1_Marque1}}": a, "{{T1_Marque2}}": b };
  var text = s.getText().asString().trim();
  if (obj[text]) s.replaceWithImage(obj[text]);
});
```

- By this modification, the URLs of `a` and `b` are used by the text in the shape.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you so much!! this worked perfectly, I can't thank you enough. I had a feeling it was because it was reading the same shape each time but I had no idea how to differentiate the shapes.

Comment: @Ilovearcticmonkeys99 About `Hi Tanaike, thank you so much!! this worked perfectly, I can't thank you enough.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Hi again Tanaike, I accepted the answer! if you'll allow a follow-up question: if I wanted to add an if statement --> if var a is empty (like "") then make a = w, where would I place that ? I placed it before the block you wrote but it doesn't take it into consideration.

Comment: @Ilovearcticmonkeys99 Thank you for your response. About your new question of `if you'll allow a follow-up question: if I wanted to add an if statement --> if var a is empty (like "") then make a = w, where would I place that ? I placed it before the block you wrote but it doesn't take it into consideration.`, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Ilovearcticmonkeys99 But this is a new question, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: yep understood :) i made a new question thanks anyway :)